# How do i make Python count how many letters are in a word?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a lab for my programming class and i need to know how to make python count how many letters are in a word excluding spaces. Can anyone help me out? This is what i have so far.

```
def Na():
    Name = raw_input("What is your name? : ")
    count [char]
Na()
```

Comment: Can you write something to count all the occurrences of the letter `'a'`?

Comment: You should tag the question as "homework" since it is for a programming class.

Comment: @LorenzoBaracchi: Nope. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(c.isalpha() for c in Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `string.ascii_letters`:

```
len([c for c in Name if c in string.ascii_letters])
```

(see @abarnert's comment below about the option)

Or, may be use regular expressions:

```
len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s))
```

Comment: Don't just do the guy's homework for him.

Comment: @user2357112 well, the question is quite specific and we are here to help :) Though, I understand that it doesn't really fit into "good SO questions" list.

Comment: Calling `letters` without calling `setlocale` is not generally useful; it will either be the same as `ascii_letters` or totally broken. If you want the former, just use `ascii_letters`. And you don't want the latter; if ASCII isn't right, either `decode` and use `isalpha`, or explicitly set the locale.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `len`?

```
len([ltr for ltr in Name if ltr.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string by spaces, joining the newly formed list and taking the length of the resulting string like so:

`len("".join(name.split(" ")))`