# Finding the number of letters in a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program to find the total number of letters in a sentence. I would like to know why my program is wrong. This is what I tried:

```
words = ["hi", "how", "are", "you"]

alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

y = 0

for i in words:
    for x in alphabet:
        n = words.count(x)
        y = y + n
print (y)
```

This program just returns 4 zeroes.

From my point of view, the program should run like this:
In the first run of the loop, i = "hi" and x = "a" . The number of "a"'s is stored in the variable n, which is then stored in the variable y. Then x takes the value "b", "c", etc until it runs trough the whole alphabet. Then the next thing is repeated until i moves to the second word.

Comment: So your program should return 11?

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes that's what I want it to do

Comment: Hint: where do you use `i`?

Comment: @DSM i is part of the first loop, I have "for i in words"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i make Python count how many letters are in a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323723/how-do-i-make-python-count-how-many-letters-are-in-a-word)

Comment: .. and is that the only place you should use it?

Comment: Are your sentences always structured as a `list` containing only letters and no punctuation/digits/etc.?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 For now yes, I am trying to solve the simplest version of this problem where I assume no punctuation, and then I'll see if I can work my way up in complexity

Comment: @DSM Not really following, I don't see where else I should put it

Comment: @Ovi: what's the point in looping over the words and putting each word into `i` if you're never going to refer to `i` again?

Comment: @DSM Haha yeah you're right I see now my mistake from the answers

Comment: A few comments on your code not related to your problem.  The variable name `i` is typically used for integers (especially loop counters) and will confuse readers.  Better to use `for word in words` or `for s in words` (`s` is often used convenience name for a string in a loop).  `y = y + n` can be shortened to `y += n`.  Even shorter would be to combine it with the previous line `y += words.count(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
n = words.count(x)
```

to

```
n = i.count(x)
```

does the trick.

**Reason**

You are saying `i` is your one word in each iteration.So you have to use `i.count(x)` to get count of `x` in `i`

Answer (score 3):

The reason your program is not working is - you are iterating the `words` with each word as `i`, but in the inner loop you are doing `words.count()` instead of `i.count()`.

This is how your for loop should look like -

```
for i in words:
    for x in alphabet:
        n = i.count(x)
        y = y + n
print (y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `n = i.count(x)`, not "n = words.count(x)"

```
words = ["hi", "how", "are", "you"]

alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

y = 0

for i in words:
    for x in alphabet:
        n = i.count(x)
        y = y + n

print (y)
```

Output

```
11
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sentence = "hi how are you"
count = sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isalpha())
```

Comment: Updated the code to incorporate @BhargavRao comment. Thanks.

Comment: This does not help the OP figure out where he went wrong.

Comment: `sum(1 for c in sentence if c.isalpha()) == sum(c.isalpha() for c in sentence)`

Comment: So is `sum(map(str.isalpha,sentence))`